# How to create CompletionItemProvider for different types of variables (Java)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, apex

I want to create CompletionItemProvider for two types Map and List (Java Language) different methods. How I can accomplish this?

Comment: Can you describe your problem in detail and what you want to expect?

Comment: @JialeDu
Yeah, so I want to create completion extension. F.e 
Map<String, Ineger> Map1 = new Map<String, Ineger>();
And I want when I type Map1. vscode gives me suggestions what to choose
Map1.get() or Map1.keySet() and so on.

Answer (score 0):

##### There are two methods in VS code that may help you:

**1. Custom code snippets**

open in sequence **File** > **Preferences** > **Configure User Snippets**. Select **java** in the command palette. This will create a `java.json` file in which you can customize the code segment according to the rules.

```json
// Just an example, it can be configured in various ways according to your needs.

    "get()": {
        "prefix": "Map1.get()",
        "body": "Map1.get()",
        "description": "insert get()"
    },

    "keySet()": {
        "prefix": "Map1.keySet",
        "body": "Map1.keySet()",
        "description": "insert keySet()"
    }
```

**Actual effect in Java code:**

[image]

select `Map1.keySet`

[image]

**2. [My Code Actions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.my-code-actions) extension**

After installation, follow the documentation to configure **settings.json**.

*Sorry the following is a simple example in **python**.*

```json
// Just an example, it can be configured in various ways according to your needs.

  "my-code-actions.actions": {
    "[python]": {
      "import {{diag:$1}}": {
        "diagnostics": ["\"(.*?)\" is not defined"],
        "text": "import {{diag:$1}}\n",
        "where": "afterLast",
        "insertFind": "^(import |from \\w+ import )"
      }
    }
  }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah, this absolutely will work BUT the first example won't work if I change the name of the variable from Map1 to productsMap, I need method which would parse type and determine

Comment: Please see my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

##### VS code can already do this.

Please make sure you have installed the **[Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java)** extension and all the extensions in the **[Extension Pack for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack)**.

**Here is my example:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I need not for Java but for Apex

Comment: Please specify your question clearly in your title and content. If it's not Java, please modify your tags.